# How to add meta information to a custom post type in wp-admin?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I've set up 3 custom post types for the wordpress website I'm working on using the following code in functions.php:

```
if ( function_exists('add_action') )
{
    add_action( 'init', 'create_post_types' );
    function create_post_types()
    {
        register_post_type('dj',Array('labels' => Array('name' => "DJ&#8217;s",'singular_name' => "DJ"),'public' => true,'has_archive' => true));
        register_post_type('gerecht',Array('labels' => Array('name' => "Gerechten",'singular_name' => "Gerecht"),'public' => true,'has_archive' => true));
        register_post_type('agenda',Array('labels' => Array('name' => "Agenda",'singular_name' => "Evenement"),'public' => true,'has_archive' => true));
    }
}
```

But in the wp-admin screen i can't add any meta info to the post. How do i fix this, or is it just not possible?

Edit: I don't want to use any plugin for this, but write the code myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add *supports* field to your initialization array, like this:

```
register_post_type('dj', Array(
    'labels' => Array(
         'name' => "DJ&#8217;s",
         'singular_name' => "DJ"
     ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'custom-fields') // notice 'custom-fields'
));
```

By default it's only *title* and *editor*, that's why you probably do not get them in the backend.

Full list of supported features looks like this:

- *title*: Text input field to create a post title.
- *editor*: Content input box for writing.
- *comments*: Ability to turn comments on/off.
- *trackbacks*: Ability to turn trackbacks and pingbacks on/off.
- *revisions*: Allows revisions to be made of your post.
- *author*: Displays a select box for changing the post author.
- *excerpt*: A textarea for writing a custom excerpt.
- *thumbnail*: The thumbnail (featured image in 3.0) uploading box.
- *custom-fields*: Custom fields input area.
- *page-attributes*: The attributes box shown for pages. This is
  important for hierarchical post types, so you can select the parent
  post.

Here is a nice writeup on the topic: [Custom post types in WordPress](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/04/29/custom-post-types-in-wordpress).

Also here is the better place to ask WordPress related questions: [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would use the plugin called [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/), which offers quite a nice interface to do this, as it offers a wide range of options.

You can use the above in conjunction with [Custom Post Type UI](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/), which allows you to create custom post types and taxonimies with a UI. FYI, you can 'Get the code' and place it into your functions.php.

An example of this:

```
register_post_type('custom-post-name', array(  'label' => 'Custom Post Label','description' => '','public' => true,'show_ui' => true,'show_in_menu' => true,'capability_type' => 'post','hierarchical' => false,'rewrite' => array('slug' => ''),'query_var' => true,'exclude_from_search' => false,'supports' => array('title','editor','custom-fields',),'labels' => array (
  'name' => 'Custom Post Name',
  'singular_name' => 'Value',
  'menu_name' => 'Custom Post Menu Name',
  'add_new' => 'Add Item',
  'add_new_item' => 'Add New Item',
  'edit' => 'Edit',
  'edit_item' => 'Edit Item',
  'new_item' => 'New Item',
  'view' => 'View Item',
  'view_item' => 'View Item',
  'search_items' => 'Search Custom Post',
  'not_found' => 'No Item(s) Found',
  'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Item(s) Found in Trash',
  'parent' => 'Parent Value',
),) );
```

you might want to look at the array and add your own descriptive data, i.e. where it says `Item` for `singular_name` and `name`.

Comment: I don't want to use a plugin. So your code looks great, i guess this is the rule what it's all about: `'supports' => array('title','editor','custom-fields',)` right?